# Tree set order Preservation - Java

Tags: java, priority-queue, treeset

I have a Priority queue which contains pair of points
I have been iterating on that queue and inserting each of the points in a pair into the Tree set.

The problem is i want to maintain the order that was in the priority queue
How should I implement the Comparator of the tree set?

Comment: The same way the priority queue produces it's order, i.e. the same comparator?

Comment: I cant do that since ,The priorty queue contains pair of points which represents lines and my comparator uses that. I cant write a comparator for a single point.

Comment: What if a point has multiple priorities, i.e. is part of multiple pairs? And does it have to be a `TreeSet` or wouldn't a `LinkedHashset` be of more use?

Comment: Please explain yourself,I rather not change my classes...

Comment: Can you have each point contain a reference back to the pair? In that case you can write a new comparator that uses the old one. Conversely, if you cannot know which pair the point comes from, I cannot see how you could order them in the same order that the pairs had.

Comment: What should I explain? Can you answer my questions?

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a possibility. I am not inserting the points themselves into the `TreeSet`, but a wrapper that keeps track of the order they were in in the `PriorityQueue`. This has the advantage that we don’t need to modify the `Point` class itself.

Here’s the wrapper class:

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Sortable<T> implements Comparable<Sortable<T>> {

    T element;
    int order;

    public Sortable(T element, int order) {
        this.element = element;
        this.order = order;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Sortable<T> o) {
        return order - o.order;
    }

}
```

Now you can do:

```
public void transfer(PriorityQueue<PointPair> from, TreeSet<Sortable<Point>> to) {
    PointPair pp = from.poll();
    int count = 0;
    while (pp != null) {
        to.add(new Sortable<Point>(pp.getLeftPoint(), count));
        count++;
        to.add(new Sortable<Point>(pp.getRightPoint(), count));
        count++;

        pp = from.poll();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you insist on the wording of your question, that the `TreeSet` should contain `Point`s and have a `Comparator`: Your `Comparator` could have its own data structure to keep track of the ordering of points, like a `HashMap<Point, Integer>` where the integer would serve the same purpose as `int order` in my code. I would consider it too complicated and I don’t see much gain, though. For you to decide.